# Image size wpf datagrid

Tags: .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a control template in wpf datagrid, Image. the sizes of images get stretched even if clipToBounds is false and no width height is specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to set the Stretch property to None?

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I thought ClipToBounds should do the same thing.